# Do parentheses work alongside "and" and "or" in conditional statements in Netlogo?

Tags: conditional-statements, netlogo, parentheses

I have written the following conditional statement in Netlogo. However, I am unsure whether the parentheses actually isolate the `OR` operator. Could someone confirm either way?

```
ifelse social-capital > median [ social-capital ] of citizens AND career-outcome > median [ career-outcome ] of citizens AND (([ policy-adoption ] of myWorkplace = "M") OR ([ policy-adoption ] of myWorkplace = "H"))
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, parenthesis with logical operators in NetLogo work as you would expect:

```
observer> show false or (true and false)
observer: false
observer> show true and (true or false)
observer: true
```

I suspect you are asking this question because you're having trouble figuring out why your condition isn't working.  I recommend breaking it up into pieces and inspect it with `show` commands if necessary to debug:

```
let c1 social-capital > median [ social-capital ] of citizens 
let c2 career-outcome > median [ career-outcome ] of citizens 
let c3 ([ policy-adoption ] of myWorkplace = "M") or ([ policy-adoption ] of myWorkplace = "H")
; add some `show` commands here if necessary...
ifelse c1 and c2 and c3 [] []
```